# Environment variables on Linux

Tags: linux, variables

I am hoping that you're able to help me I am trying to understand how use the /proc file system or profile settings. I am trying to write a script which pulls the temp of the CPU and a list of peripherals attached to a SUSE device. This would be using native functionality rather than a tool. Is there a path of sorts to the variable for temp of the CPU and a list of attached devices?

Hopefully it makes sense.

Regards

QuinsUK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get temp use "sensors":

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +63.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +60.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

or look at the `/sys/class/hwmon/`

```
$ cd /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/
{ cat temp3_label; cat temp3_input; }
Core 1
58000
```

For attached devices:

lspci - List PCI:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G35 Express DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 82G35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566DC Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
```

lsscsi - List scsi devices:

```
$ lsscsi
[3:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST3500418AS      CC38  /dev/sda 
[4:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  SONY     DVD RW DRU-190A  1.63  /dev/sr0
```

lsusb - List usb buses and device details:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

[hwinfo](http://www.novell.com/documentation/suse91/suselinux-adminguide/html/ch11s05.html) — all at once